# Fetch request with parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, fetch

Hello

I think the question has already been asked but I did not really find anything that could help me.

So here you have an AJAX request  perform with jquery

```
$.ajax({
    type:"GET",
    async:false,
    data: {pageSize:1000},
    url:BRAPI_V1_URL_ENDPOINT + URL_CALLS,
    traditional:true,
    timeout:TIMEOUT,
    success:function(jsonResponse) {
        var dataList = getDataList(jsonResponse);
        mainLoop: for (var i=0; i<REQUIRED_CALLS.length; i++)
        {
            for (var j=0; j<dataList.length; j++)
                if (dataList[j] != null && REQUIRED_CALLS[i] == dataList[j]['call'])
                    continue mainLoop;
            unimplementedCalls.push(REQUIRED_CALLS[i]);
        }
    },
    error:function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        errorMsg = "No BrAPI source found at " + BRAPI_V1_URL_ENDPOINT + " (error code " + xhr.status + ")"
    }
});
```

You can see that we can give a data parameter at the time we write the request
Here I gave {pageSize:1000} as parameter.
Now I use fecth to make my Ajax request but I don't know the way to give one or more parameters with fecth. So that's my question !

Thanks

Comment: First You need to know How to ask the question? then You need to know what is Paginantion? and Why to use Pagination?

Comment: Add parmeter like data: {pageSize:1000,key:value,key:value}, and also add your server side

Comment: Could you be more precise because I don't really understand